# eth0 is not listening on port 80 when PPTP is not connected

Tags: iptables, routing

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 20.04 on my cloud server.

Everything was working fine before I do some modifications to some network related configurations.

I have a PPTP VPN server running on my server.

Now I have the following problem:
My nginx server should be listening on port 80 on all interfaces.
But it doesn't.

When I curl public IP in the server it works.

```
 curl {my.public.ip}:80 -I  --interface eth0
```

but when I run curl from another remote computer, it doesn't.

```
curl {my.public.ip}:80 -I
```

Then I connect to my PPTP server from laptop.

Surprisingly,
`curl {my.public.ip}:80 -I`
seems to be working on any computer now. (Doesn't matter whether the computer I running curl is connected to the VPN or not).
But as I disconnect my laptop from the VPN, the port 80 of eth0 is closed again.

But this problem doesn't affect for any other port (443, 22, 21, 81, 3306 seems to be working properly)

Here are the latest commands I entered (I think one of them affects causes the above problem but I'm not sure)

```
service pptpd restart
sysctl -p
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -p 47 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I cannot let my laptop go sleep because my web server will be stopped listening on eth0, port 80...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Now I run the following command only and it works smoothly.

```
service pptpd restart
iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring the nginx vhost to listen to your server's ip address no port 80 and not on all interfaces. And by that I mean that, rather than using:

```
listen 80;
```

in nginx, try using:

```
listen server-ip 80;
```

This way your nginx server only binds to port 80 to that specific ip address and not on all interfaces.